# How I got jQuery Quicksand working with WordPress?

Tags: jquery, filters

I have been tryin to make this plugin work but I failed badly. I have the code like below:

The `portfolio-terms` is filtering buttons:

```
            <div id="portfolio-terms">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="all current"><?php _e('All', 'framework'); ?></a><span>/</span></li>
                    <?php 
                    wp_list_categories(array(
                            'title_li' => '', 
                            'taxonomy' => 
                            'skill-type', 
                            'walker' => new Portfolio_Walker(),
                            'show_option_none' => ''
                        )
                    ); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The `portfolio-items` is the images that need to be filtered:

```
       <ul id="portfolio-items" class="<?php if($magic_door) : ?>enabled<?php endif; ?> clearfix">

               <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <li id="portfolio-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php echo $output; ?>visible">

                        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                            <a class="entry-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>

                            <?php tz_featured_image(get_the_ID(), TRUE); ?>

                        </div>

                    </li>

               <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </ul>
```

I was using this jQuery code:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
  <script>

    jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Clone applications to get a second collection
    var $data = $("#portfolio-items").clone();

    //NOTE: Only filter on the main portfolio page, not on the subcategory pages
    $('#portfolio-terms ul li').click(function(e) {
        $("ul li").removeClass("active");   
        // Use the last category class as the category to filter by. This means that multiple categories are not supported (yet)
        var filterClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1)[0];

        if (filterClass == '.all current') {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('#portfolio-');
        } else {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('#portfolio-[data-type=' + filterClass + ']');
        }
        $("#portfolio-items").quicksand($filteredData, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'swing',
        });     
        $(this).addClass("active");             
        return false;
    });
});

  </script>
```

But does not work.
here my theme test: http://stakk.it/

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is entirely your problem, but you have a syntax error here:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
```

...you need to add the trailing slash to `bloginfo('template_directory')`, like so:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your browser source, your loop markup is working properly, but your quicksand script link doesn't appear to be output anywhere. Where and how are you calling it?

**EDIT 2**

Okay, [the quicksand script is loading now](http://stakk.it/wp-content/themes/garnish/js/jquery.quicksand.js?ver=3.2.1); however, **it appears to be using a [jQuery no-conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) format that will cause it to execute immediately, rather than on `document.ready`**. You might try changing this format:

```
(function($) {
    // quicksand script
})(jQuery);
```

...to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // quicksand script
});
```

Also: you're loading a TON of scripts. I would make sure that you have them cascaded properly, so that dependent scripts load *after* their dependencies.

**Note: using `wp_enqueue_script()`, which includes a `$deps` argument, is especially helpful here, and is the best-practice implementation for enqueueing scripts.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried, but doesn't work. I think that the problem is in the script code. For example this is correct: var $filteredData = $data.find('#portfolio-'); ??

Comment: See updated answer. It appears that your quicksand script link isn't getting output anywhere?

Comment: See updated answer. The quicksand script *is* loading now, but it *wasn't* at the time I updated my answer previously.

Comment: Now I solved the problem but I don't understand why the images vanish.

Comment: If it appears to be a related problem, update your question; if it is a *new* or *unrelated* problem, start a new question, with all relevant details to help others help you solve it.